# Prevent Outlook 2010 from adding a category to a conversation

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, email-client, exchange-2010

The following steps are performed in Outlook 2010 with the latest service pack and cumulative rollup, while in conversation view. The default Outlook 2010 rule that clears categories on inbound mail is active, and SendPersonalCategories and AcceptCategories are explicitly set to 0 in the registry:

1. Send an email to my own inbox
2. Forward the email to myself
   Note: This generates a conversation in the conversation view
3. Select the conversation item (not an individual sub-item!) and categorize it
4. Forward the latest email in the conversation to a different mailbox
   Note: At this point, the category is applied to the email in Sent Items, but is NOT sent along with the outbound email
5. Reply to the email from said mailbox
6. At this point, the reply once it is in my inbox is categorized with the category of the conversation.

How do I prevent:

1. The copy of the outbound email in sent items from being categorized
2. The inbound email from getting categorized

I don't care about the category of the conversation, I only care about

A) The category of the individual emails
B) The conversation itself

Note: This is NOT the original problem case, but the simplest test case I could come up with. Maybe someone can simplify it further.

Comment: Sounds like you're applying the Category to the Conversation, and then when the email comes back it's recognized as part of the conversation and is added to it, and as soon as it's added to the conversation it's given the category you assigned to the parent conversation. _Is_ the last reply (in points 5 and 6) being grouped with the conversation by Outlook once received?

Comment: You got it right. This would only be slightly bothersome in the example case described, but now imagine this with a team mailbox and somebody misclicking. Once this happens, the only way to get Outlook to stop this behaviour is to clear all categories for the conversation itself - which clears the categories of all emails involved in the conversation.

Comment: The problem is you're up against two competing things.  conversation group things, if you want to use them, then you have to expect that things you apply to the Conversation will affect all it's child messages.  If you don't want that, you're only option may be to stop using Conversation mode, or make sure people are categorizing conversations. But maybe someone else has a better idea. ;)

Comment: Well, basically what I want/need is a way to make it so the categories are completely independent of the conversation, or at least so if I assign a category to a conversation, it's only applied to all /current/ emails, and not all future emails.